# azure devops git branch ahead and behind but files are the same

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to merge changes for 8 files from a Dev branch to a Main branch, when I create the PR in Azure DevOps it says there are 50+ files that need to be merged from Dev to Main but that is not correct because when I manually compare the files they are exactly the same and the 50+ files were previously merged.

If I compare the branches, it says Dev is ahead of Main by 22 changes, but when I compare the files in those changes, the content is exactly the same. Why is this and how to resolve?

I ran this command and it wrongly shows differences, doing a compare in a diff tool shows the files are exactly the same.

```
git diff origin/dev...origin/main --word-diff
```

Even when I commit the merge, from dev to main, the very next PR it tries to merge the exact same changes, but again there is no actual differences in the files, git is wrong, but not sure how to get out of this loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** When the *source* branch of your PR is a *shared* branch, such as `dev`, the *only* merge strategy you should use when completing a PR is regular "Merge".

**Detailed answer:**

AzDO has 4 merge strategies: Regular Merge, Squash, Rebase and fast-forward, and Semi-Linear Merge (aka Rebase, then merge). Only a regular Merge (which uses "no fast-forward") doesn't rewrite the source branch; all of the other 3 options do rewrite the commits from the source branch before merging.

You are not using the regular merge strategy when completing your PR from `dev` into `main`, but instead are using one of the other three options. I know this because you stated:

> Even when I commit the merge, from dev to main, the very next PR it tries to merge the exact same changes...

That wouldn't happen if you use a regular merge when completing the PR, but is precisely what would happen if you don't use a regular merge when completing that PR. As a rule of thumb, always use a regular merge when the *source* branch of the PR is a shared branch. (Another related rule of thumb is to never  rewrite a shared branch.) The other 3 merge types are designed to be used when the *source* branch of the PR will be deleted after the PR is completed, such as a feature or topic branch.

> If I compare the branches, it says Dev is ahead of Main by 22 changes, but when I compare the files in those changes, the content is exactly the same. Why is this and how to resolve?

This is happening because the definition of "ahead" in this context is only about *commits*, and is unrelated to the *state* of the files. So that just means that `dev` can reach 22 commits that are not reachable by `main`. As mentioned above, when you squashed or rebased `dev` when merging it into `main`, that left 22 commit IDs that never ended up on `main`. The fact that the state of the files in the tip of `dev` is the same as those in the tip of `main` is not relevant for determining "ahead" and "behind".

> I ran this command and it wrongly shows differences, doing a compare in a diff tool shows the files are exactly the same.

```
git diff origin/dev...origin/main
```

This is simply because your diff command has 3 dots instead of 2 dots (or no dots). When you diff with 3 dots you are diffing `origin/main` with the merge-base of `origin/dev` and `origin/main`, so that command is shorthand for (using Bash):

```
git diff $(git merge-base origin/dev origin/main) origin/main
```

> when I create the PR in Azure DevOps it says there are 50+ files that need to be merged from Dev to Main but that is not correct because when I manually compare the files they are exactly the same and the 50+ files were previously merged.

Note the diff you see in the PR is the 3 dot diff instead of 2 dots, because most of the time that's what people wish to see. Showing 3 dots becomes confusing though when you have lots of cherry-picks, or in your case rebases or squashes of the source branch already present on the target branch. In your particular case, if you view the changes in the merge commit (which you can see from the 3 dots menu on the right side), you'll see there are in fact no changes.

Answer (score 1):

you may be better off creating a feature branch of only the files you want to modify and create a new PR off that feature branch. Then after you merge to `main`, you can update `develop` branch with the new changes.

```bash
git checkout -b feature/my-changes
git checkout develop -- ../path/to/each/of/my/files.json
git commit -m "feat: some new changes"
git push -u origin feature/my-changes
<create a PR from `feature/my-changes` to `main`>
git checkout develop
git pull origin main
```

EDIT:
if you can only merge from `dev` to `main`.  try this

```bash
## on `develop`
git add <files>
git commit -m "temp commit"
git pull origin main
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git commit --amend 
<update the commit message>
git push origin develop
```

- temporarily commits your modified files
- pulls changes from main to update develop branch
- resets your `HEAD` to the temp commit but keeps the changes from the merge
- allows you to modify the commit message
- push your changes to `develop` remote
- create your PR from `develop` to `main`

EDIT x2:
as a last resort:

```bash
# on `develop`
- git checkout -b feature/my-changes origin/main
- git add <files>
- git commit -m "temp commit"
# now you're on `feature/my-changes`
- git branch -D develop
- git fetch origin
- git checkout develop
- git checkout feature/my-changes -- <path to each file>
```

- temp store your 8 modified files in a feature branch with the `HEAD` at `main`
- delete `develop`
- fetch a new copy of `develop`
- checkout the 8 files from the feature branch to bring them back into `develop`
- then you should be fully up to date and able to commit your changes as normal

Comment: This would allow me to only merge the few changes I care about right now, but the two branches would still continue to be out of sync. The 50+ files that git thinks are not equal between the two branches, that problem would still exist, right? Our workflow is to merge feat to dev then merge dev to main. Your idea may allow the 8 changes to be merged but would not solve the dilemma, unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: if your workflow is only to merge from `dev` to `main`, your `dev` branch may be out of sync with `main`.  commit your 8 files that changed on `dev` and then try pulling changes from `main`.  then your `dev` branch should sync and you'll be able to push to `main` afterwards.

Comment: I actually tried that by merging from main to dev, but it had no affect